# Recommender system result curation

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

so I want to ask if there's some sort of curation algorithm that arranges/sends results from a recommender system to a user.

For example, how Twitter recommends feeds to users. Is there some sort of algorithm that does that or Twitter just sorts it by highest number of interactions with that tweet (based on time posted too).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing like that.
Actually the recommendation system model is made in such a way, where it sort it based on Content Based filtering or Collaborative filtering according to the view stats of the user.

There are some algorithms like calculating co-relation between the view stats of the user and the content which is in twitter, and then recommend it.
Or Cosine Similarity and Cosine distance can also be used to calculate distance between view stats and content of twitter to  recommend.
You must explore also other recommendation system, which is based on other algo's like Pearson Correlation, Weighted Average,etc.